# Custom Pyramid Scaffold does not install template folder

Tags: python, pyramid

After running setup.py for my scaffold.

```
pcreate -l
```

shows the appropriate listing but when I try to run

```
pcreate -s my_project_template SomeProjectName
```

I get that 'no such file or directory /install/path/my_project_template/scaffolds/my_project_template' error

The following is my setup.py file for the scaffold

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='my_project_template',
      version='0.1',
      packages=find_packages(),
      include_package_data=True,
      zip_safe=False,
      entry_points = """\
        [pyramid.scaffold]
        my_project_template=my_project_template.scaffolds:MyProjectTemplate
      """
     )
```

My Project template class in my `__init__.py` under my_project_template/scaffolds/

```
class MyProjectTemplate(PyramidTemplate):
    _template_dir = 'my_project_template'
    summary = 'My own starter project template'
```

Does anyone know why the my_template_project folder is not copied when I install my scaffold?

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic issue with not packaging your package for distribution correctly. You need to ensure that your project has a MANIFEST. Optionally you could instead use `setuptools-git` or `setuptools-hg` to automatically distribute all version controlled files.

Comment: Or `setuptools-subversion` for current svn versions.

Comment: That's a documentation problem. I didn't see the MANIFEST anywhere in the example links. https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/tree/master/pyramid/scaffolds. Can we add this to the docs?